# Gemsets file isn't working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rvmrc

I have a folder which contains a file named `gemsets.rvmrc`. The file contains this:

```
rvm use @pa
```

Running this code in the terminal successfully switches over to the correct gemset. I'd heard that putting this file in the folder would do that automatically when I CD to that folder, but this isn't the case. Running a ruby file in the same folder, test.rb, gives errors until I run that code in the terminal to switch to the correct gemset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gemsets.rvmrc` is not a supported file, it should be just `.rvmrc`, but using just gemset not always works - check this bug: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2078